# make perspective header with css3 transform

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I need a little slider presentation

I wish I can make **Reporting** heading from [**this plain version**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4GDJ/2/) ([view fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/J4GDJ/2/embedded/result/)) to something like this:

[image: result needed]

Also would be nice having:

1. also icon move in css animation rather than using jQuery
2. rotation 3d animated after icon steps in
3. having more `.slide` elements that appear in sequence

No need of cross-browser hassle, everything will run in chrome, latest version.

---

## Edit

I see I can easily handle transitions adding classes with jQuery but, since adding in sequence on different elements seems not easy I have to set timeouts matching transition durations:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('.icon').addClass('in');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('h1').addClass('on');
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.icon').addClass('out');
    }, 2000);    
});
```

[**See JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4GDJ/3/)

**Any better solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use setTimeout, you could break up each animation into a separate function, and string them together via callbacks like this:

```
$().ready(function(){
    animationOne();
});

function animationOne()
{
     $('.icon').transition( { 'margin-top': 0 }, 2000, 'in', animationTwo ); 
}

function animationTwo() 
{
    $('h1').transition( { 'font-size': '5em', perspective: 200, rotateY: -15 }, 1000, 'in-out', animationThree );
}

function animationThree()
{
     $('.icon').transition( { 'margin-left': '-600px' }, 2000, 'in-out'); 
}
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YFZdP/)

Basically, once the animation is finished, the next function is called, allowing you to do consecutive animations. I'm using [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) in the above example, which is perfect if you want to do a lot of transitions/transforms without having to deal with large css files.

Comment: Accepted and +1 for suggesting jQuery Transition too

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to apply `-webkit-perspective` and `-webkit-perspective-origin` to the heading container:

```
-webkit-perspective: 150; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-perspective-origin: 10% 10%; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

See [**live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4GDJ/5/)

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know about those CSS rules. +1!

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate things along the z-axis with CSS3's transforms:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg);
```

Of course these properties are animatable (I don't know if that's a word) with CSS3 transitions:

```
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transfom;
```

(I only used `-webkit-` because you said in the question it would only be run in Chrome.)

If you add other properties to the transition properties too, you can animate them with `$("#whatever").css()`.

Comment: can you try this in my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4GDJ/2/)? `rotateZ` seems not the right one...

Comment: I was just trying to, but it seems my old laptop can't handle the newest version of JSFiddle. I'll try tomorrow (but there is a chance I forget it. In that case just leave another comment - if you haven't got a better answer by then). @neurino

Comment: Aha, I just discovered it should have been rotateY. Editing now. @neurino

Comment: The problem is, even with the right rotation that seemes `rotateY` the text does not see to pop out with the _R_ getting smaller and the _g_ getting bigger. [*See this*](http://jsfiddle.net/J4GDJ/4/)

Comment: Try changing the `-webkit-transfom-origin` to the center of the header. @neurino

Comment: it's where I moved it from trying to fix it ;). Sorry, seems not to help. I can wait for a live example :) @11684

Comment: I'm not sure if I can fix it if you can't. But I'll try.